# Spring Security OAuth2 pure resource server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We already have an OAuth2 authorization server set up, so I need to create a corresponding resource server (separate server).  We plan to use the Spring Security OAuth2 project.  Their documentation for setting up a resource server:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oAuth2#resource-server-configuration

`token-services-ref` should point to the token-handling bean.  However it seems like the token handling is done by the server itself even though it is the resource server.  There doesn't seem to be any remote token services class or any configuration relating to a remote server.  This is in contrast with the CloudFoundary UAA (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/samples/api/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml) which has:

```
<bean id="tokenServices"
  class="org.cloudfoundry.identity.uaa.oauth.RemoteTokenServices">
  <property name="checkTokenEndpointUrl" value="${checkTokenEndpointUrl}" />
```

Is there any way to use Spring Security OAuth2 for a resource server that communicates with a separate OAuth2 Authorization server?  How can I set the communication endpoint?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is possible as long as the authorization server and resource server(s) access a shared `tokenStore` (e.g. using `JdbcTokenStore` with a common `dataSource`). You can just use `DefaultTokenServices` with a reference to your shared `tokenStore`. Below is an example Spring config which you should be able to tweak to fit your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="myRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- This is not actually used, but it's required by Spring Security -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" />

<oauth2:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth2:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <security:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<oauth2:resource-server id="myResource" resource-id="myResourceId" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<security:http pattern="/myPattern/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_READ" method="GET" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_READ" method="HEAD" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_READ" method="OPTIONS" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_WRITE" method="PUT" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_WRITE" method="POST" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="SCOPE_WRITE" method="DELETE" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="myResource" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <security:expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</security:http>
</beans>
```

Comment: Yessss! Thank you, @chris-h.  Plug-n-played this to a quick 40 minute success, followed by a celebratory game of nerf h-o-r-s-e.

Answer (score 9):

Yes its possible. Like you have already mentioned in your question, `RemoteTokenServices` is the solution.

I have created one sample which has separate auth and resource server. Its just a sample to give a quick idea about the concept and open for extension.

[Spring-AngularJS-OAuth2-Sample](https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample)

Comment: Don't we have any properties that can be configured to achieve this?

Comment: @Rites in your example the RemoteTokenServices are using de /oauth/check_token endpoint. what about token validation using /oauth/token_id endpoint? Do you how this can be achieved?

Comment: do you have an example with RemoteTokenServices for facebook graph?

Comment: @All any has idea about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672643/how-to-configure-resource-id-in-resource-server-using-oauth2-security