# Spring Boot- Invalid access token error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm currently working on a simple **Spring Boot application** where I pass client_id and secret to get the access token which gets me a refresh and access token.

But then when I try to access resources(my REST API) using that token (with this URL: *curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ead8ba5d-88ad-4531-a821-db08bf25e888" localhost:8081/my-end-point* ), it doesn't work for me and gives me following error-

**{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: ead8ba5d-4531-db08bf2fe888"}**

This is how my endpoint looks like-

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/my-end-point")
public class PrincipalResource {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Principal oauth(Principal principal) {
        /*
         * Translate the incoming request, which has an access token
         * Spring security takes the incoming request and injects the Java Security Principal
         * The converter inside Spring Security will handle the to json method which the Spring Security
         * Oauth client will know how to read
         *
         * The @EnableResourceServer on the application entry point is what makes all this magic happen.
         * If there is an incoming request token it will check the token validity and handle it accordingly
         *
         *
         */


        return principal;
    }
} `
```

Comment: its due to authentication problem,  It could be helpful to you 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596036/spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-always-returning-invalid-token

Comment: I'm following this article for the implementation of oauth2 -  https://dazito.com/java/spring-boot-and-oauth2-with-jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that in your **AuthServerOAuth2Config**
  `security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");`

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {     
    security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");       
}
```

and start generating some tokens by making **POST** requests to your server at URL:**localhost:yourport/oauth/token**

for example:

```
http://localhost:8085/oauth/token?client_secret=secret&client_id=web&grant_type=password&username=kalaiselvan&password=kalaiselvan
```

it will return token

```
 {
   "access_token": "8b816685-b7da-4996-a3e2-ff18b4538a2b",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "f458c09b-f739-4488-be0f-2b0e3c5a62d1",
   "expires_in": 637,
   "scope": "read"
 }
```

[image]

copy the **access_token** from the response data and make new **POST** request
http://localhost:8085/account
[image]

I hope it will be helpful to you

Comment: based on my post request response -> access_token which is from **localhost:8085/oauth/token?client_secret=secret&client_id=web&grant_type=password&username=kalaiselvan&password=kalaiselvan**

Comment: how you get this token `9e3cee66-ebd9-4e0e-acd1-718152794552`

Comment: with this query : 
**localhost:8081/oauth/token?client_secret=secret10&client_id=web10&grant_type=password&username=2871&password=631356**

Comment: There's one thing, the first time when I hit the oauth/token api it generated refresh token for me. But now it doesn't even for new users

Comment: But it's in my database web10 and secret10

Comment: db?  which table? `oauth_client_details`

Comment: @shreya  Authentication tab->OAuth2.0 -> Access Token

Comment: what is the version of your postman @shreya? if  <5    means update it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. Actually in my db i've changed all my **varbinary** datatype to **int**. After changing it, it worked for me