# How to configure resource id in resource server using oauth2 security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I am trying to create Authorization server and resource server.
When tried to get access token from Authorization server its working and getting access token with following details.

```
{
    "access_token": "5ffbc2d7-2a27-4f08-921f-f7de2410b5f5",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "d0fb85b3-52e0-45e0-84dc-ed38d55176a6",
    "expires_in": 599,
    "scope": "READ",
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "delete_profile"
        },
        {
            "authority": "update_profile"
        },
        {
            "authority": "read_profile"
        },
        {
            "authority": "create_profile"
        },
        {
            "authority": "ROLE_admin"
        }
    ],
    "resource_ids": [
        "RESOURCE_ID1"
    ]
}
```

with the access_token when trying to hit one service(resource server configured)
getting response. 
But In DB oauth_client_details table resource_ids column the resource id =RESOURCE_ID1 and in Resource Server I provided resource id =RESOURCE_ID11
intensionally to verify. Though its returnng data,it should  give authority exception.

My sample code snippet as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    @Bean
    TokenStore jdbcTokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(jdbcTokenStore())
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "RESOURCE_ID11"; // resource id is defferent to DB oauth_client_details resource id

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

}
```

DB data understanding:

```
INSERT INTO `OAuthTest`.`oauth_client_details` (`client_id`, `client_secret`, `scope`, `access_token_validity`, `refresh_token_validity`, `resource_ids`, `authorized_grant_types`, `additional_information`) VALUES ('APP1', 'password', 'READ', '600', '10000', 'RESOURCE_ID1', 'authorization_code,password,refresh_token,implicit', '{}');


INSERT INTO `OAuthTest`.`user` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `enabled`, `accountNonExpired`, `credentialsNonExpired`, `accountNonLocked`, `account_non_expired`, `account_non_locked`, `credentials_non_expired`, `account_expired`, `account_locked`, `credentials_expired`) VALUES ('1', 'admin', 'password', 'admin@app.com', '1', '1', '1', '1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```